# Django: Check if record exists in two different states

Tags: django, django-models

I am using two models to build a chat system between users:

```
class Chat(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
class Participant(models.Model):
    chat = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='participants')
    sender = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

One record in the participants model represents the ability to send messages from the user sender to the user receiver.

Thus, for a valid private chat between A and B, two records will exist, one with A as sender and B as receiver and vice versa.

Since one user will always be the one starting the chat but the first participant record could be with A as sender or B as sender, I need to know if there's a clean and cheap way to check if both records exist when a user tries to initiate a chat, and return the chat id if it exists.

How do I search for the existence of records (sender=A, receiver=B) and (sender=B, receiver=A) in the same query?

Comment: So the users `A` and `B` are known in advance?

Comment: User A is the authenticated user and user B is supplied as the target user to start a chat with. The query is for checking if there is a preexisting chat that could have been started by either user.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) objects to create complex queries including matching on one condition OR another

```
query = Participant.objects.filter(Q(sender=A, receiver=B) | Q(sender=B, receiver=A))
query.count() == 2  # If you want to check that 2 records exist
```

`|` in this case creates a filter with an "OR"

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of two `JOIN`s here, like:

```
Chat.objects.filter(
    participants__sender=user_a,
    participants__receiver=user_b
).filter(
    participants__sender=user_b,
    participants__receiver=user_a
)
```

This will result in a query like:

```
SELECT chat.id, chat.created
FROM chat
INNER JOIN participant ON chat.id = participant.chat_id
INNER JOIN participant T5 ON chat.id = T5.chat_id
WHERE participant.receiver_id = user_b AND participant.sender_id = user_a
  AND T5.receiver_id = user_a AND T5.sender_id = user_b
```

It will thus return all the `Chat` objects for which two such `Participant` objects exist.

The above is not ideal however, since we make two `JOIN`s. In case there is a `unique_together` constraint on the participants, as in:

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    chat = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='participants')
    sender = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['sender', 'receiver']
```

We can just count the number of `Participant` objects, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

Chat.objects.filter(
    Q(participants__sender=user_a, participants__receiver=user_b) |
    Q(participants__sender=user_b, participants__receiver=user_a)
).annotate(
    nparticipants=Count('participants')
).get(
    nparticipants=2
)
```

This will use the following query:

```
SELECT chat.id, chat.created, COUNT(participant.id) AS nparticipants
FROM chat
INNER JOIN participant ON chat.id = participant.chat_id
WHERE (participant.receiver_id = user_b AND participant.sender_id = user_a)
   OR (participant.receiver_id = user_a AND participant.sender_id = user_b)
GROUP BY chat.id
HAVING COUNT(participant.id) = 2
```

We can use `.get(..)` here, since due to the `unique_together` constraint, it is guaranteed that there is at most one `Chat` object for which this will exist. We can thus then handle the situation with a `Chat.DoesNotExist` exception.

I am however not really convinced that the above modeling is ideal. First of all the number of records will scale *quadratic* with the number of participants: for three participants, there are six records. Furthermore a `Chat` is probably conceptually speaking not "directional": there is no sender and receiver, there are two or more peers that share information.

Comment: I was trying to model the directional nature of the allowed communication, since user A might want to send a message to user B but user B does not want to receive messages from user A. How else would you propose modeling this? Is this taking normalization too far and I should have just stored it horizontally (user_a, user_b, user_a_blocked, user_b_blocked)?